# md-autocomplete md-require-match not working when setting the expression dynamically

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I'm setting the autocomplete validation `md-require-match = true/false` based on the radio button selection.

Default validation is `md-require-match = true` so that user should select an item from autocomplete list. Once it load and user enter some value to the autocomplete input and clear the value, `searchForm.autocompleteField.$error` have this value: `{"md-require-match":true,"required":true}`

Now I'm selecting the radio button which is going to set  `md-require-match = false`. But Its not removing `md-require-match":true` validation error from `$error` list.

Here is the code pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbrJoJ

How to fix this validation issue ?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue but I used `$setValidity('md-require-match', true);` on check of the `true` radio button. Now I am able to set the validity on click of radio button.